# Storyboard initWithCoder ok, but when is encodeWithCoder called

Tags: ios, xcode

I am experimenting with Storyboard and NSCoder. The initWithCoder is called all right, when the ViewController is being loaded from the Storyboard.

How and when to call the encodeWithCoder? I guess it is done from Storyboard loading some other View or disposing the ViewController. I tried dismissViewControllerAnimated on the ViewController containing the encodeWithCoder method.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

encodeWithCode is called when an object is serialized into a byte stream so it can get written to disk / send over a network or so ... for a storyboard it will never be called as it is never written to disk only read from disk

Comment: encodeWithCoder is actually the 'opposite' of initWithCoder